# How Can I Add a Sum with GROUPBY in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel-5.6

I want to make a query in Laravel using ORM and return the result in JSON.

```
SELECT * FROM `reviews` 
     GROUP BY `school_fk` HAVING (SUM(re_count) > 4)
```

I tried more ways but it didn't work for me although I run it in MySQL. This was the last trial for me:

```
Reviews::groupBy('school_fk')->havingRaw('sum(re_count)>', 2)->get();
```

> error : Argument 2 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::havingRaw() must be of the type
>   array, integer given

Can anyone help?

[reviews table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuSRR.png)

Answer (score 1):

Put all your `having` part inside the first parameter of the function. As of now you're splitting it into two parts.

```
Reviews::groupBy('school_fk')->havingRaw('sum(re_count) > 2')->get();
```

Comment: it gives the error : Syntax error or access violation in the laravel docs 
$orders = DB::table('orders')
                ->select('department', DB::raw('SUM(price) as total_sales'))
                ->groupBy('department')
                ->havingRaw('SUM(price) > ?', [2500])
                ->get();